# How to install/setup psftp in open suse linux?

Tags: linux, files, suse

We need to do a file transfer from an open SUSE Linux server to a Windows server and vice versa.

We are required to use `psftp` for the file transfer. Can anyone tell me how to setup/install `psftp` in our Linux server and the steps to do a transfer?

and please tell me how to know if `psftp` is already installed in my server (both OpenSUSE Linux and Windows).

Comment: Is this just the matter of setting up SFTP to enable file transfers or is there a programming aspect to this problem? Currently, this is not clear. If there is none, you should consider 'moving' your question to superuser.com or serverfault.com

Answer (score 1):

In order to connect to Linux via SFTP all you need to do is have SSH installed. Since you are using Suse, you probably already have it installed. See if you can connect to localhost using this:

```
sftp localhost
```

If you get a login prompt, you are ready to go. All you need to do from the remote computer is to use PSFTP entering the external IP address of your linux box; for example:

```
sftp 1.2.3.4
```

If ssh is not installed, you can install it by launching `Yast2` and selecting SSH package. Once is installed it *usually* is started by default. In any case, you can configure it to start at boot time from `Yast2` as well

Comment: question, does sftp is the equivalent of psftp in windows?

Comment: @user998632 yes, `psftp` is just a user interface for `sftp`, which is the underlying protocol.